# No available namespaces. You must have owner or maintainer permissions to link namespaces

Tags: jira

I am trying to access to my Gitlab repository from Jira. I have downloaded the app and authorize it in Gitlab.

[image]

[image]

But, I can't see my repository

[image]

Comment: Did you use issue keys in your branch names, commit messages or pull request titles?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be maintainer or owner role for a namespace.  Click into one of your projects, the url will be like this:
https://your.gitlab.com/mynamespace/myprojectname

Then go to this url:
https://your.gitlab.com/groups/mynamespace/-/group_members

There you can set the account you are authenticating the jira app with as maintainer/owner of the group (aka namespace).  If it's your own account, you need another admin to set u, u can't change urself (apparently)